# TChart LoadChartfromFile not getting series data

Tags: delphi, charts, teechart

When using TChart in RadStudio 10.2 using Delphi, I would like to save my chart and then be able to load it with all the settings and data included.

I am successfully saving the chart using the following code:

```
  With SaveDialog do begin
    Filter:='Teefiles|*.tee';

  if Execute then
     SaveChartToFile(Chart,SaveDialog.FileName,True);
  end;
```

However, when I load the chart back, I only get the chart title. The loaded chart includes no series or data.

```
  Chart.Free;
  tmpChart := Chart.Create(Self);
  With LoadTextFileDialog do begin
      Filter:= 'Teefiles|*.tee';
      if Execute then
        LoadChartfromFile(tmpChart,LoadTextFileDialog.FileName);
  end;

  Chart := tmpChart as TChart;

  With Chart do begin
    Parent:=Self;
  end;
```

For troubleshooting purposes, I printed out the Chart.SeriesCount after I load the Chart and I am getting a 0.

Comment: Set  fourth parameter `textformat`  to True and check whether file really contains series data

Comment: Fourth parameter of which function call are you referring to?

Comment: SaveChartToFile

Comment: The line `tmpChart := Chart.Create(Self);` is wrong, it should be `tmpChart := TChart.Create(Self);` Objects are always instantiated with class's constructor.

Comment: Ok I ran the code   With SaveDialog do begin
    Filter:='Teefiles|*.tee';

  if Execute then
     SaveChartToFile(Chart,SaveDialog.FileName,True, True);
  end;                                                                                                          And am still getting the same results. I am very much a beginner with TChart so please forgive me.

Comment: I changed the line to tmpChart := TChart.Create(Self) and still no change in my results.

Comment: But did you look at the file as MBo suggested, to verify it contains series data.

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that. I added a fourth parameter "true" to the SaveChartToFile function call:                                                                                              if Execute then
     SaveChartToFile(Chart,SaveDialog.FileName,True, True);
  end;

Comment: OK, now open text file `yourfilename.tee` and check for something like `object Series1...` containing `Data = { 010A000000DB3FC6BD...`

Comment: My working example (Berlin, Techart): `var Ch: TChart; begin  SaveChartToFile(Chart1, 'test.tee', True, True);  Ch := TChart.Create(Self);  Ch.Parent := Panel2;  LoadChartFromFile(Ch, 'test.tee');`

Comment: Yes I have 5 TLineSeries objects with data

Comment: What series do you have? How do you fill them? Does loadchart work for the simplest example - single TLineSeries with a pair of points?

Comment: There are 5 series in this case that I am filling with data by continuous calls in a TAdTerminal (this communicates with a processor and gets a new data point for each of the 5 series every line). The Chart works perfectly while getting new data and adding it to the chart. Its just when I want to go back and load a file that I am not having success.

Comment: There are two possibilities: your mistake (like Chart.create etc) or TChart error. I don't see multiple complaints in the net - but IMHO these functions are rarely used. I'd prefer to save and load data, not component with data.

Comment: Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Yes, save data only (or separately if you really need to save all the component state)

Comment: I have found the cause of this error and it was a simple one. I just need to inlcude TeeEdiSeri in my uses. Not having this did not give me an error but just did not populate the series when loading. Thanks everyone for the help.